# Using retrofit & dagger how would I create an app where I can easily switch out end points?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, dagger, dagger-2

Currently the way I do it is I have an ApiConfig class that looks like this:

```
public class ApiConfig {

public enum Build{
    RELEASE("https://api.endpoint.com"),
    STAGE("http://api.stage.endpoint.com"),
    DEV("http://api.dev.endpoint.com");


    public String endpoint;

    Build(String endpoint){
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }
  }
}
```

And I have a ApiModule that takes in a build type so I instantiate the component like so:

```
ApiComponent component = DaggerApiComponent.builder()
            .apiModule(new ApiModule(ApiConfig.Build.DEV))
            .build();
```

So, now if I want to change the endpoint, I change ApiConfig.Build.DEV to ApiConfig.Build.STAGE or ApiConfig.Build.RELEASE. Is this the right way to go about this? Eventually, I want to be able to press a button to switch between the three.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is what i do:

I have a service factory class based on a internet example. see the code below.

When i need to create a Instance of my service i call.

```
service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(GithubService.class,
            GithubService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);
```

So if you add your 3 endpoints to the GithubService interface. On the click event of your desired view just make the call to the ServiceFactory with the desired SERVICE_ENDPOINT.

example.

```
public interface GithubService {
    String RELEASE_ENDPOINT = "https://api.endpoint.com";
    String STAGE_ENDPOINT = "http://api.stage.endpoint.com";
    String DEV_ENDPOINT = "http://api.stage.endpoint.com";

    @GET("/users/{login}")
    Observable<UserResponse> getUser(@Path("login") String login);
}
```

in your RELEASE button onClick() call :

```
private GithubService service;

service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(GithubService.class,
            GithubService.SERVICE_ENDPOINT);
```

in your STAGE button onClick() call :

```
private GithubService service;

service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(GithubService.class,
            GithubService.STAGE_ENDPOINT);
```

in your DEV button onClick() call :

```
private GithubService service;

service = ServiceFactory.createRetrofitService(GithubService.class,
            GithubService.DEV_ENDPOINT);
```

Service Factory code:

```
public class ServiceFactory {

    private static final String TAG = ServiceFactory.class.getSimpleName();
    /**
     * Creates a retrofit service from an arbitrary class (clazz)
     * @param clazz Java interface of the retrofit service
     * @param endPoint REST endpoint url
     * @return retrofit service with defined endpoint
     */
    public static <T> T createRetrofitService(final Class<T> clazz, final String     endPoint) {
        final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setLog(new RestAdapter.Log() {
                    @Override
                    public void log(String message) {
                        Log.v(TAG, message);
                    }
                })
                .setEndpoint(endPoint)
                .build();
        T service = restAdapter.create(clazz);

        return service;
    }
}
```